# Number to ASCII String Converter

Tags: python, list, ascii

I am trying split an integer into a list and convert every element into it's ASCII character. I want something like this:

```
    integer = 97097114103104
    int_list = [97, 97, 114, 103, 104]

    chr(int_list[0]) = 'a'
    chr(int_list[1]) = 'a'
    chr(int_list[2]) = 'r'
    chr(int_list[3]) = 'g'
    chr(int_list[4]) = 'h'

    ascii_char = 'aargh'
```

Is there a way I can do this? I want it to work for any number such as  `'65066066065'`, which will return `'ABBA'`, or `'70'`, which will return `'F'`. The issue I'm having is that I want to split the integers into the right numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you take the decimal ascii values, so 3 digits are a char.
Using x mod 1000, would give you the last three digits of the number.
iterate on the number.
Example code:

```
integer = 97097114103104
ascii_num = ''
while integer > 0:
    ascii_num += chr(integer % 1000)
    integer /= 1000
print ascii_num[::-1] #to Reverse the string
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way can be using [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap).

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> integer = 97097114103104
>>> temp = str(integer) 
>>> temp = '0'+temp if len(temp)%3==2 else temp
>>> [chr(int(i)) for i in textwrap.wrap(temp,3)]
['a', 'a', 'r', 'g', 'h']
```

And for your other example

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> integer = 65066066065
>>> temp = str(integer) 
>>> temp = '0'+temp if len(temp)%3==2 else temp
>>> [chr(int(i)) for i in textwrap.wrap(temp,3)]
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

For `integer = 102103`

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> integer = 102103 
>>> temp = str(integer) 
>>> temp = '0'+temp if len(temp)%3==1 else temp
>>> [chr(int(i)) for i in textwrap.wrap(temp,3)]
['f', 'g']
```

If you want to make the padding of zeroes "fool-proof" you can use `zfill` as in

```
temp = temp.zfill((1+len(temp)/3)*3)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
integer = 97097114103104
#Add leaving 0 as a string
data='0'+str(integer)
d=[ chr(int(data[start:start+3])) for start in range(0,len(data),3)]
```

Yields

```
['a', 'a', 'r', 'g', 'h']
```